# Plotting values obtained using numerical integration

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics

I have an integral which doesn't give a closed definite expression. The command

```
Integrate[x DiracDelta[r x - y] Exp[1/g^2 {Cos[x2 - x] + Cos[x2] + Cos[y+x2]}], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, {x2, -Pi, Pi}]
```

returns the expression itself. Therefore I evaluate this numerically using `NIntegrate` in order to understand the behaviour of the integral with $r$ and $g^2$.

In this situation my preferred way is to to obtain plots of the integral with respect to $g^2$ for a fixed $r$, and also with $r$ for a fixed $g^2$. How do I combine `Plot` and `NIntegrate` together and get a plot for the same over some values for $r$ and $g^2$? In other words, I would need to iterate `NIntegrate`, and construct a list of points so as to plot on the graph. How do I achieve that?

Comment: You may define a function `f[r_?NumericQ, g_?NumericQ]:=NIntegrate[...]`.

Comment: @Alx Can you make it an answer? How would I generate the plot afterwards?

Comment: `Plot3D[f[r,g],{r,...},{g,...}]`, you need to put in ranges for `r` and `g`.

Answer (score 6):

Progress can be made by integrating over `y` only (with the correction that `{…}` be replaced by `(…)`).

```
Integrate[x DiracDelta[r x - y] Exp[1/g^2 (Cos[x2 - x] + Cos[x2] + Cos[y + x2])], 
    {y, 0, 2 Pi}, Assumptions -> r > 0 && 0 < x < 2 Pi]
(* E^((Cos[x - x2] + Cos[x2] + Cos[r x + x2])/g^2) x HeavisideTheta[2 Pi - r x] *)
```

In contrast, if `r < 0`, the result is `0`, as one would expect.

The remaining integrals take the form,

```
Integrate[E^((Cos[x - x2] + Cos[x2] + Cos[r x + x2])/g^2)
    x HeavisideTheta[2 Pi - r x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {x2, -Pi, Pi}]
```

**Edit**: which can be simplified further to

```
Integrate[E^((Cos[x - x2] + Cos[x2] + Cos[r x + x2])/g^2) x, 
    {x, 0, 2 Pi Min[1, 1/r]}, {x2, -Pi, Pi}
```

Now, if `g^2` is much greater than `1`, then the remaining integrations can be performed with the exponential ignored.

```
Integrate[x, {x, 0, 2 Pi Min[1, 1/r]}, {x2, -Pi, Pi}, Assumptions -> r > 0]
(* (4 Pi^3 Min[1, 1/r]^2 *)
```

For `g^2` not large, the remaining integrals must be performed numerically along the lines suggested by Alx in a comment above, but a 2D plot is slow.

```
f[r_?NumericQ, g_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[E^((Cos[x - x2] + Cos[x2] + Cos[r x + x2])/g^2) x, 
    {x, 0, 2 Pi Min[1, 1/r]}, {x2, -Pi, Pi}, 
    Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]
```

A 1D plot for `g == 1` is

```
Plot[f[r, 1], {r, 0, 4}, MaxRecursion -> 2, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {r, None}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

For a small value of `g`, the curve is somewhat different.

```
LogPlot[f[r, 1/10], {r, 0, 4}, MaxRecursion -> 3, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {r, None}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Peaks lie at `r = 1` and very close to `r = 0`.

**Addendum**

The further simplification identified by Andreas (+1), equivalent to

```
f[r_?NumericQ, g_?NumericQ] := 2 Pi NIntegrate[BesselI[0, g^-2 
    Sqrt[3 + 2 Cos[x] + 2 Cos[r x] + 2 Cos[(1 + r) x]]] x, {x, 0, 2 Pi Min[1, 1/r]}, 
    Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]
```

reproduces the plots above about an order of magnitude faster.  For completeness, we provide a plot of the values at the two peak values as functions of `g` (rescaled by `Exp[-2.94 g^-2]` to keep the curves readable.

```
LogPlot[{f[.02, g] Exp[-2.94 g^-2], f[1, g] Exp[-2.94 g^-2]}, {g, 1/10, 3},
    ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {g, None}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, Automatic}]
```

The blue and orange curves correspond to `r = 0.02` and `r = 1`, respectively.

[image]

Comment: For my case `g^2` is not large, so I won't be able to use this. Thanks though.

Comment: Even  so, doing the `y` integration symbolically speeds the subsequent numerical computations and may provide insight.  I just added a plot for `g == 1` to illustrate the plotting process.

Comment: I see your point. Let me see if I can use this.

Answer (score 4):

if the range of the x2 integration may be shifted to {0,2π} then it can be done and plotted like:

```
g = 2.; Plot[{NIntegrate[
   E^((Cos[x - x2] + Cos[x2] + Cos[r x + x2])/g^2) x HeavisideTheta[2 Pi - r x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {x2, 0, 2 Pi}], 
  2 Pi  NIntegrate [x BesselI[0, 1/g^2 \[Sqrt](3 + 2 Cos[x] + 2 Cos[r x] + 
           2 Cos[(1 + r) x])] HeavisideTheta[2 Pi - r x], {x, 0, 
      2 Pi}] + 10}, {r, 0, 4}]
```

because

```
Integrate[Exp[a Cos[x]] Exp[c Sin[x]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
is (* 2 Pi BesselI[0,Sqrt[a^2+c^2]]*)
```

Above is valid if you shift the integration range by any s (for instance s=-Pi):

```
Integrate[Exp[a Cos[x]] Exp[c Sin[x]], {x, s, 2 Pi+s}]
is (* 2 Pi BesselI[0,Sqrt[a^2+c^2]]*)
```

Comment: Thanks, let me see if this works out.